# jQuery Enter key can't work for other forms

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with my jQuery enter key. For form login the enter key is working goods but for form reset password, the enter key is not working but with click it can.

Not working means: if I press enter, it will redirect to action page without any validation in my JS.

Now I want to set the enter key for form reset password.

Here is my code so far:

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()               
    {
        $(document).bind('keypress', function(e)
        {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $('#button_sign_in').trigger('click');
            }
        });

        $('#button_sign_in').click(function()
        {
            if ( $("#username").val().length == 0 )
            {
                $('#button_sign_in').attr("disabled", false);
                $('#username').focus();
            }
            else if ( $("#password").val().length == 0 )
            {
                $('#button_sign_in').attr("disabled", false);
                $('#password').focus();
            }
            else if ( $("#username").val().length == 0 && $("#password").val().length == 0 )
            {
                $('#button_sign_in').attr("disabled", false);
                $('#username').focus();
            }
            else
            {
            $.ajax
            ({
                url: "login",
                type: "post",
                data: $('#login_form').serialize(),
                dataType:'json',
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    if (data.status=='SUCCESS') 
                    {
                        window.location='home.php'; 
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $('#button_sign_in').shake(4,6,700,'#CC2222');
                        $('#username').focus();
                        $('#password').val("");
                        $('#button_sign_in').attr("disabled", false);
                        $("#info").text("Wrong username or password.");
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log('error:'+e);
                }
            });
            }
        });

$(document).bind('keypress', function(e)
        {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $('#button_reset').trigger('click');
            }
        });

        $('#button_reset').click(function()
        {
            if ( $("#email").val().length == 0 )
            {
                $('#button_reset').attr("disabled", false);
                $('#email').focus();
                $("#info2").text("Email is required.");
                $('#button_reset').shake(4,6,700,'#CC2222');
            }
            else
            {
            $.ajax
            ({
                url: "check_email",
                type: "post",
                data: $('#reset_form').serialize(),
                dataType:'json',
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    if (data.status=='FOUND') 
                    {
                        $("#info2").html('<span class="success">Password reset instructions has sent to your email.</span>');
                        $('#email').val("");
                        $('#email').focus();
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $('#button_reset').shake(4,6,700,'#CC2222');
                        $('#email').focus();
                        $('#button_reset').attr("disabled", false);
                        $("#info2").text("Email is invalid.");
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log('error:'+e);
                }
            });
            }
        });
    });
```

And the HTML code for Login Form like this:

```
<form id="login_form">
                            <div id="info"></div>

                            <table>                                 
                                <td><input type="text" name="username" class="input" id="username" placeholder="Username or email"/></td>

                                <tr>

                                <td><input type="password" name="password" class="input" id="password" placeholder="Password"/></td>

                                <tr>

                                <td><input type="button" id="button_sign_in" class="button_sign_in" value="Sign in"/></td>

                                <tr>

                                <td>
                                    <span class="keep_logged_in"><input type="checkbox"> Keep me logged in</span>
                                </td>
                            </table>
                        </form>
```

and for Form Reset like this :

```
<form id="reset_form" class="collapse">
                            <div id="info2" class="info2"></div>
                            <table class="t_info">
                                <td><input type="text" name="email" class="input" id="email" placeholder="Email"/></td>

                                <tr>

                                <td><input type="button" id="button_reset" class="button_reset" value="Submit"/></td>
                            </table>
                        </form>
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You're binding two `keypress` handlers to the `document`, and neither pays any attention to which field the user was typing in when they pressed enter.

Comment: hmm.. any example for that ? :)

Comment: Unrelated to your JS question (there are already some good answers) but your HTML could do with some updating too. For example, you need to ensure your TD tags are wrapped with appropriate TR tags: <table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate keypress handlers bound to the `document`, and neither does anything to test which field the user was typing in when they pressed enter.

Why not bind these to each of your forms instead:

```
    $("#login_form").bind('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#button_sign_in').trigger('click');
        }
    });

    $("#reset_form").bind('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#button_reset').trigger('click');
        }
    });
```

That way, when enter is pressed within a form that form's button is the one you trigger a click on.

Comment: Really thank you very much for your help @nnnnnn. Now working good :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try adopting a more generic approach by selecting the relevant (closest) `form` element and then triggering the submit. Additionally I would also recommend considering applying your `keypress` event to more specific elements, like so:

```
$('input, select, textarea').bind('keypress', function(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but it seems you want both forms to be submitted both on click and on enter press?

If this is the case, I think you should bind your AJAX calls to form.submit and then add an e.preventDefault to prevent the submission to act with default behaviour (because you want to use your AJAX not the default submission behaviour).

Somethin like this :

```
$('#login_form').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault()

    // now do your AJAX call for login_form here (the code of your $('#button_sign_in').click)

})

$('#reset_form').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault()

    // now do your AJAX call for reset_form here (the code of your $('#button_reset').click)

})
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

you should change the `type` of both buttons to `submit`